# Swap keys in nested objects using JQ

Tags: json, jq

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), how can I transform:

```
{ "a": {"b": 0}, "c": {"d": 1}}
```

into:

```
{"b": {"a": 0}, "d": {"c": 1}}
```

without knowing the name of the keys in the source?

(I know that this can lose data in the general case, but not with my data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative using `with_entries`:

```
with_entries(.key as $parent
  | (.value|keys[0]) as $child
  | {
        key: $child,
        value: { ($parent): .value[$child] }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def swapper:
  . as $in
  | reduce keys[] as $key
      ( {}; . + ( $in[$key] as $o
                  | ($o|keys[0]) as $innerkey
                  | { ($innerkey): { ($key): $o[$innerkey] } } ) ) ;
```

Example:

```
{ "a": {"b": 0}, "c": {"d": 1}} | swapper
```

produces:

```
{"b":{"a":0},"d":{"c":1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses jq streams and variables:

```
[
  . as $d
| keys[]
| $d[.] as $v
| ($v|keys[]) as $vkeys
| {
    ($vkeys): {
       (.): ($vkeys|$v[.])
    }
  }
] | add
```

It is easy to lose track of what is what at the end so to see more clearly what's going on here is a slightly expanded version with additional comments and variables.

```
[
  . as $d                    # $d:     {"a":{"b":0},"c":{"d": 1}}
| keys[] | . as $k           # $k:     "a", "c"
| $d[$k] as $v               # $v:     {"b": 0}, {"d": 1}
| ($v|keys[]) as $vkeys      # $vkeys: "b", "d"
| ($vkeys|$v[.]) as $vv      # $vv:    0, 1
| {
    ($vkeys): {              # "b": {     "d": {
       ($k): $vv             #   "a": 0      "c": 1
    }                        # }        , }
  }
] | add
```